# React delete on click item from array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm trying to delete item from Cart if user click a button.

I've made a `Cart.js` component which shows every object from my array of objects.

Code which shows elements in Cart component looks like this

`Cart.js`

```
{props.orderItems.map((item) => {
          return (
            <div key={item.id} className="content__orders">
              <div className="orders__item">
                <p>{item.name}</p>
                <p>{item.price}zł</p>
                <input type="submit" onClick={onItemDelete(item)} />
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
```

and the `onItemDelete()` method looks like

```
const onItemDelete = (event) => {
    orderItems.filter((item) => item === event);
};
```

The problem is everything deletes on Component render and I can't figure out what is happening. The onClick event handler should works only on click but somehow it only works on render and I don't know why.

I've tried to check what `console.log(event)` will show but it shows every element in `orderItems` which is array of objects.

How can I get only one item from the array and delete it?

Comment: First of all onclick is not correct. It should be like this: `onClick={() => onItemDelete(item)}`

Comment: You have filter backwards, and you're not doing anything with the filtered list of items.

Comment: That was the main problem. After few changes, everything seems to work properly. Thanks a lot!